# Generate an interface from an array of field names

Tags: typescript

I have an array of supported languages

```
['en', 'de', 'fr', 'it']
```

Many of classes should have those fields

```
class MyObject {
 
 id: number;
 name: string;

 en: string;
 de: string;
 fr: string;
 it: string;
}
```

Some classes can also have other fields that are connected to languages

```
class DescriptionsObject {
 
 description_en: string;
 description_de: string;
 description_it: string;
 description_fr: string;

}
```

There can be added other such fields.

I don't want to add each such field for each language manually, is there a way of doing it faster by using magic of TypeScript ?

Comment: You can't do string manipulations in the type system

Comment: I think [extends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) will help you